# Django URL give me space between root and included urls

Tags: python, django, url

So I create an url in root/project/urls.py with this lines

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('app.urls'))
]
```

while in my root/app/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import UserView, AuthenticationView

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', UserView.as_view()),
    path('auth/', AuthenticationView.as_view()),
]
```

So it is expected to give me `http://localhost:8000/users/register` and `http://localhost:8000/users/auth` urls.

Meanwhile my request doesn't behave as expected.

[image]

apparently it returns me a space between the root path and include path. I check my root/project/settings.py file I don't find any weird settings. Does anybody know what is going on?

Comment: You are `include` ing `accounts.urls` when your urls is actually `app.urls`. Can you try that?

Comment: Are you actually going to `/users/auth/`? Looks like you are requesting just `/users/`

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov I tried to include /auth/ and /register/ inside the root urls by using include.

Comment: use this one. url(r'^your_url/$', views.your_view)

Answer (score 4):

**The space is just for displaying how the URL is built up, on the debug screen only**.

I have experienced the same and at first I too thought Django somehow added the space. In the end it really is that there is no match between the URL's specified and the URL in your browser. Safari doesn't display the full url, so error can happen quickly...

Some additional [info on urls in Django can be found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/).

Answer (score 3):

The error message in your screenshot states that the request URL is http://localhost:8000/users does not exist.

Here you redirects `/users/` to `app.urls`:

```
path('users/', include('app.urls'))
```

But in `app.urls`, you never included a pattern for when the URL ends with only "/users/". Instead, "/users/register/" and "/users/auth/" are both specified.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', UserView.as_view()),
    path('auth/', AuthenticationView.as_view()),
]
```

So http://localhost:8000/users/register and http://localhost:8000/users/auth should be valid URLs, but http://localhost:8000/users is not.

You can add another URL pattern for when the URL ends at "/users/":

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', AuthenticationView.as_view()), # maybe the same as /auth/ ?
    path('register/', UserView.as_view()),
    path('auth/', AuthenticationView.as_view()),
]
```

---

In conclusion, Django's actually not wrong about that page does not exist (404), it's because you hadn't match http://localhost:8000/users in any of the `urlpatterns`.

Comment: it returns me a warning `WARNINGS:
?: (2_0.W001) Your URL pattern '^$' has a route that contains '(?P<', begins with a '^', or ends with a '$'. This was likely an oversight when migrating to django.urls.path().
`

Comment: Opps, my bad, it should be an empty string.

Comment: It just solved by itself even without add an index path for users. So weird LOL. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to use regular expressions?

```
path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls)
```

Otherwise in the Django 2 version the urls schema has been changed, I use url function instead the path function, that can be a possible fix for your problem

Comment: There is `re_path` for using regular expressions.